# Winston add newline between logs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using winston to log from my node app. I want to add a new line in between of my logs. How can I do that? I dont want to change the winston's default logging format. Is there a way this can be achieved?

```
const path = require("path");

const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: path.join(__dirname, 'out.log') })
  ]
});

logger.info("This is log1");
logger.info("this is log2");
```

This generates something the following:

```
{"message":"This is log1","level":"info"}
{"message":"this is log2","level":"info"}
```

I just simply want a newline between the both like:

```
{"message":"This is log1","level":"info"}
                                               //----- this new line is what I am looking for.
{"message":"this is log2","level":"info"}
```

Comment: Create a custom transport

Comment: Thought of that but documentation does not say how I can enter just text like " \n " to my log.

Comment: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#formats use a custom format and add just a blank line at the end